# Unable to get JsonArray value

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch JsonArray from php to android using volley. But I am getting the following error.

```
org.json.JSONException: Value <!-- of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Following is my JsonArray response which I am getting from php.

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "subject_name": "Entrepreneurship",
        "percentage": 1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
    },
    {
        "subject_name": "Advanced Computing Platform",
        "percentage": 1.1399999999999999023003738329862244427204132080078125
    },
    {
        "subject_name": "Enterprise Application Platforms",
        "percentage": 0
    },
    {
        "subject_name": "Major Project",
        "percentage": 0.340000000000000024424906541753443889319896697998046875
    }
]
}
```

Following is my PHP code which I am using to fetch the JsonArray from db.

```
$get = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM subject_dtls WHERE course_sem='$student_course'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get))
{
    $sub_id = $row['subject_id'];
    $subject_name = $row['subject_name'];
    $total_hours = $row['total_hours'];


    $get12 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT sum(duration) as du_sum FROM attendance_count WHERE subject_id='$sub_id' AND roll_numbers = '$official_id'");
    while($row12 = mysqli_fetch_array($get12))
    {
        $duration = $row12['du_sum'];

        if ($duration=='') 
        {
            $duration = 0;
        }

        $percentage = 0;
        $percentage = ($duration * $total_hours)/100;

        $temp = array();
        $temp["subject_name"] = $subject_name;
        $temp["percentage"] = $percentage;

        $value["result"][] = $temp;

    }
}

echo json_encode($value);
```

Following is my Java Code which I am using to get the Json Response.

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {

                JSONArray result = response.getJSONArray("result");

                for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = result.getJSONObject(i);

                    String subject_name = jsonObject.getString("subject_name");
                    String percentage = jsonObject.getString("percentage");

                    // Each time create a new instance and then save the value.
                    CheckAttendanceAdapter caa = new CheckAttendanceAdapter();

                    caa.setSubject_name(subject_name);
                    caa.setPercentage(percentage);
                    arrayList.add(caa);
                }

                data = new String[arrayList.size()][10];
                for (int j = 0; j < arrayList.size(); j++) {
                    CheckAttendanceAdapter c = arrayList.get(j);
                    data[j][0] = c.getSubject_name();
                    data[j][1] = c.getPercentage();

                    tableView.setDataAdapter(new SimpleTableDataAdapter(getActivity(), data));
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

And following is the screenshot of the error.

[image: screenshot of the error]

Please do tell me, what I am doing wrong.

Comment: instead of `jsonObject.getString("percentage");` try `jsonObject.getDouble("percentage"); `

Comment: @akhilesh0707 I have tried by only fetching the **jsonObject.getString("subject_name");** and removing the **percentage**, but same error.

Comment: that is the `response` its string type? or jsonObject?

Comment: @akhilesh0707 **public void onResponse(JSONObject response)**, JSONObject

Comment: before iterating check the value of response

Comment: @akhilesh0707 just tried the following line `Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`  not getting any Toast.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168428/discussion-between-rahul-and-akhilesh0707).

Comment: try adding `header('Content-Type: application/json')` before echo

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need to parse manually JSON response, or simply you don't know that there another way to consume REST service.

I suggest you use Retrofit library to build REST client. It's easier to write and easy to maintain. To consume a REST service with Retrofit you need to write your service interface and an associated model:

```
public class Result {
  public String subject_name;
  public double percentage;
}

public class YourResponse {
  List<Result> result;
}
```

And REST client:

```
public interface YourService {
  @GET("result")
  Call<YourResponse> getResult();
}
```

And the code to invoke your service:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("<your server url>")
    .build();

YourService service = retrofit.create(YourService .class);
service.getResult().execute();
```

More information about retrofit is [here](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but it will be little troublesome for me to change lots of code for a single fragment.

Comment: Give a try to Retrofit, if you wrote a lot of REST client in the way you show in your answer, with Retrofit you will reduce you code.. code that you have to maintain. You can always try only to this service... and leave other service with volley